# Can I have a real time query on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, arduino

I am working on an open source project where I am using an Arduino controller to play with light output. The data source I want to feed it is being logged real time into an [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) database. I want to watch data, feed it to the controller so that I can visually watch what occurs to the data being placed into the database. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: For your application the difference probably doesn't matter, but Windows isn't a [real-time operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system).

Comment: I see what you mean. It definitely makes sense to do it that way if... as you said my project were more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your viewing application poll the database for new log items every, say, 50 ms. Make your viewing application remember the ID of the last record that was fetched from the database and include this ID in your query like this:

```
select *
from LogItems
where ID > @lastSeenID
```

This is the most simple solution I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for that! It is a great way of doing it.